# How to provide option to select geographic part for content

Tags: nodes, google-maps, location

I'm working on Drupal6 travel website and stuck with how to provide option to users to select the right geographic part of the world that they are going to write story about that place.

Should I provide AJAX drop down for example: 
1 - Countries  (So when user select country)
 then 
2 - Cities/States (Related to the selected country)

If there is something else for that ?

Any help would be appreciated :)

Zafar

Comment: I wish you luck... imho, upgrade to D7, install https://drupal.org/project/references and https://drupal.org/project/chosen and https://drupal.org/project/shs, then http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_csv a taxonomy of countries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [Location](https://www.drupal.org/project/location) module. It will help  you to attach location info with nodes. More details from the module's project page:

> The Location module allows real-world geographic locations to be associated with Drupal nodes, including people, places, and other content. The Location module allows admins to collect addresses, geocode them (translate addresses to lattitude/longitude), and associate locations with Drupal nodes and users. Location data is automatically used to generate GeoRSS within your existing RSS feeds.

Answer (score 0):

Check out these modules:

[Leaflet](https://www.drupal.org/project/leaflet)

> Field formatter that can show a map for fields that contain geospatial
>   data. Views integration that plots data on a map (using the sub module
>   Leaflet Views). Lightweight and easy to use API for defining maps and
>   displaying data on a map

[Address Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/addressfield)

> Standardized storage of international postal addresses based on the
>   xNAL standard (the same format used by Google Maps for geocoding)
>   Per-country edit form and formatting of addresses Proper formatting of
>   address forms and output on a country by country basis as they are
>   added to the module; see the address formats issue queue for pending
>   country support Feeds integration for address importing Rich snippets
>   / semantic markup via the Schema.org module

[Gmap](https://www.drupal.org/project/gmap)

> The GMap module provides an interface to the Google Maps API within
>   Drupal. It integrates with the Location module to provide users a
>   clickable map for entering latitude and longitude, as well as to
>   display maps of Drupal nodes and users. GMap can be used to create
>   interactive maps with various map markers and content in map bubbles,
>   taking advantage of Drupal's other content management features. The
>   module also provides a Views display plugin which allows users to
>   display the results of a view on a Google map.